# what is the last Compact FrameWork for Windows-CE 6.0?

Tags: installation, windows-ce

what is the last Compact FrameWork for `Windows-CE 6.0` ?

for cpu: `624MHz Marvell,PXA32X-P`

Answer (score 1):

.net CF should be supported by any CPU that CE still supports.

Win CE 6.0 can run CF 3.5.

[link to versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms172550.aspx)